# Web server on Linux with php 7.4 fails on file_get_contents() for 1 URL only

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have problem using `file_get_contents()` for 1 particular URL only. I have full access to both the source and fetching server.

**The following ARE set:**

**On getting server**
`allow_url_fopen = On`

**On source server**
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

This is the source data I am trying to get. [https://dataflexlink.tech/rest/plugin-info/](https://dataflexlink.tech/rest/plugin-info/index.php) You can see in the headers that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*`

In fact, in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtbcrguf/) you can see that source goes over `ajax` on a completely different server without a problem.

**This is the code on the getting server**

**NOTE**: timeout is set to 5 seconds to stop browser from hanging.

```
$dflURL = 'https://dataflexlink.tech/rest/plugin-info/';

$options = ['http' => [
        'timeout' => 5,
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Content-type:application/json'
]];

$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$test = file_get_contents($dflURL,false,$context);
```

This very same getting server does not have a problem getting data from another server e.g. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

This is the getting server which has a problem http://test.tioray.com. This getting server doesn't:  [http://test.web-dewd-test.co.uk/](https://test.web-dewd-test.co.uk/)
You can see both get from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 without an issue. You can also click the button at the bottom to see the data come over on `ajax` from both without a problem.

I'm completely at a loss as to what is causing the problem. The php settings across [http://test.web-dewd-test.co.uk/](https://test.web-dewd-test.co.uk/) and http://test.tioray.com seem identical, but only the first works without an issue.

Comment: The response from `https://dataflexlink.tech/rest/plugin-info/` has the `Content-Type` set to `text/html` while what you want is `application/json`. Adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to the source's PHP code would be the solution for that issue

Comment: CORS does not play a role in server to server communications like these. I suggest you dig deeper into the specific server that has the issue to figure out what is happening e.g. maybe it's not configured to accept a "content-type" header for get requests that have no body?

Comment: @Weetz I look at the header and see `content-type application/json`

Comment: @apokryfos you are right, but I added a CORS check to prove that it wasn't an origin issue. Also, doesn't the response provide a header and body? I can see one by opening the URL in Firefox. In any case, I guess I have to get on the phone to GoDaddy support. Wish me luck!

Comment: @dewd okay, that wasn't the case when I made a request

Comment: Try changing your `Content-Type` header to `Accept: application/json`

Comment: @Weetz I inadvertently created a race condition. I noticed it immediately after I posted  and changed it immediately. You had a dirty read!

Comment: @apokryfos no luck. You can see the header under `Couldn't file_get_contents()` here: http://test.tioray.com/